# Animation states declared but never used

Tags: angular

I have animation states which are being used in the templates. When running npm start I get errors that the animation states are declared but never used which is not correct. Using Angular2 2.4.4

Here is one example, but I am getting the same error for all the animation states in the project. This used to work before I updated, Angular and Webpack.

inside the template

```
<div [@searchState]="searchState"> </div>
```

in the component

```
@Component({
  selector: 'myComp',  
  styleUrls: ['./myComp.style.scss'],
  animations: [
  trigger('searchState', [
  state('compact', style({
    height: '40px'
  })),
  state('normal', style({
    height: '64px'
  })),
  transition('compact => normal', animate('100ms ease-in')),
  transition('normal => compact', animate('200ms ease-out'))
])
 ],
    templateUrl: './myComp.template.html'
})


 export class HeaderComponent implements OnInit, OnDestroy {
   searchState: string;
  ngOnInit() {
     this.searchState = 'compact';
 }
 }
```

Comment: But.. how can we help.. there is no code

Comment: Hi, @PierreDuc sorry about that see updated question

Comment: Although all properties are public in Typescript, could try to explicitly mark the searchState property with `public` access modifier? Also are you using tslint or other linting tool? When the error is shown?

Comment: Hi @GeorgeK good suggestion but without luck. I am using tslint ~4.2.0